# C# string interpolation with variable format

Tags: c#

I need to format a variable with string interpolation, and the format string is another variable:

here is my sample code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 12345;

    Console.WriteLine($"Test 1: {i:N5}");

    var formatString = "N5";

    Console.WriteLine($"Test 2: {i:formatString}");
}
```

Test 1 works, Test 2 don't work.

What's the exact syntax for Test 2 ?

Answer (score 8):

The shortest way you can do this 'syntactically' without String.Format, is using `ToString`:

```
$"Test 2: {i.ToString(formatString)}"
```

Answer (score 7):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Test 2: {0:formatString}", i));
```

As the `formatString` is in the format string, you would nest `String.Format` calls to put the value in the format string:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(String.Format("Test 2: {{0:{0}}}", formatstring), i));
```

This isn't supported with string interpolation.

Comment: Hard to believe, because if so, would be a big limitation compared with the old C# string.format

Comment: interesting by your explanation this can be done with half interpolation and half string format.`Console.WriteLine($"Test 2: {{0:{formatString}}}", i);`

Comment: but another problem arise if I assign it to a string, rather than writing to a console. StyleCop will signal a warning: here's my code.var test = string.Format($"Test 2: {{0:{formatString}}}", i); the warning is "SA1127 : CSharp.Readability : Use string interpolation rather than string format."

Comment: @user2289427: I would suggest that you format the value using `ToString` instead: `$"Test 2: {i.ToString(formatString)}"`.

Comment: @Guffa, what if type is object rather than int ?

Comment: @user2289427: Then I don't know of any convenient way of formatting it.

Comment: @user2289427 - You can always implement your own formatting method (or extension method if you need to attach it to an already existing type)

Answer (score 1):

C# has no syntax that will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this piece of code and it seems to work:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 12345;

    Console.WriteLine("Test 1: {0:N5}",i);

    var formatString = "N5";

    Console.WriteLine("Test 2: {0:" + formatString + "}", i);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: It's not string interpolation though.

Comment: It's exactly what I would like to avoid, the old syntax of C#

Comment: And could you do with a double string.Format?

`Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Test 2: {{0:{0}}}",formatString), i);`

Comment: It would be even worse as you're using _twice_ the syntax he wants to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

The string interpolation happens in the compilation stage. You cannot use variables in the format strings because of that.

Comment: The fact that it runs at compile-time has nothing to do with that limitation.  The compiler could easily concatenate your string into the format string.

Comment: @SLaks It could do whatever, but it doesn't. Would a better answer be "because it's done that way"?

Comment: A better answer would just remove your first sentence; it isn't relevant at all.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a simple extension method that allows you to call a formattable `ToString` method on any object. The `IFormattable` interface is the same way that `string.Format` or interpolated strings would use to format an object of unknown type.

```
public static string ToString(this object value, string format, IFormatProvider provider = null)
    => (value as IFormattable)?.ToString(format, provider) ?? value.ToString();
```

And to use:

```
object i = 12345;
var formatString = "N5";

Console.WriteLine($"Test 2: {i.ToString(formatString)}");
```

Comment: You are creating a static method on `object`, for which a similar implementation already exists on the `Int32` type, which is used in the question. Also you're boxing/unboxing the `int` which is unnecessary.

Comment: You didn't realize that the object is of UNKNOWN type. Yes, I used an int as example. But the intent is to format an unknown type object.

Comment: Then its better to make a static method on ’IFormattable’ not ’object’ to show the intent and supported types.