# formatting decimals using string format

Tags: c#, string-interpolation, c#-6.0

```
public static string PadZero(this double number, int decimalPlaces)
    {
        var requiredFormat = "0." + "".PadRight(decimalPlaces, '0');
        var something = $"{number:requiredFormat}";

        return number.IsNotZero() ? something: string.Empty;
    }
```

This is a helper function to pad zeros to a double **number**, user can pass the number of zeros that is required to be padded through **decimalPlaces**.
Above function fails my unit tests, output received is {requiredFormat} in all test cases.
I have just replaced: `var something = $"{number:0.00}";` with a generic variable **requiredFormat** that can handle any number of zero padding.

Comment: Why is there a $ outside of the quotes where `something` is declared?

Comment: @rsbarro [Interpolated Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) - A C# 6 feature.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384287/c-sharp-string-interpolation-with-variable-format

Comment: @MAV Thanks! Time to download Linqpad 5! =]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your example. The first is that the value of `something` is not going to produce a string that can be used to format a number. The second is that you are not using `something` to perform a number format by using `string.format`.

So first off, the statement:

```
var something = $"{number:requiredFormat}";
```

is not going to give you the result that you want, which would be a string that looks something like:

```
{0:0.0000}
```

Try changing the code to read:

```
var something = $"{{0:{requiredFormat}}}";
```

If you do `Console.WriteLine(something)` after that statement executes you can inspect the value of `something` to make sure it is what you are looking for.

After that, change this line:

```
return number.IsNotZero() ? something: string.Empty;
```

to read:

```
return number.IsNotZero() ? string.Format(something, number) : string.Empty;
```

Even with Interpolated Strings, you have to build the variable format and apply it in two separate steps.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help.