# Variable decimal formating in string interpolation

Tags: c#, .net, string, c#-6.0

I have looked around for this, but I'm not sure it's possible with string interpolation (I'm using VS2015).

```
string sequenceNumber = $"{fieldValuePrefix.ToUpper()}{separator}{similarPrefixes + 1:D4}";
```

Is there any way to make `D4` a variable ? [Some say yes, some no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384287/c-sharp-string-interpolation-with-variable-format). Apparently, VS2015 C#6.0 is able to do it.

This works, it will return a string like `WMT-0021`, depending on fieldValuePrefix (WMT), separator (-) and the value of similarPrefixes (20). But I'd like the "D4" part to be a method argument instead of hardcoded in there.

Any ideas ?

Comment: If `similarPrefixes` is an `int` this should work.  What are the exact values you are using and the output you get versus the desired output?  Or are you getting errors?

Comment: @juharr It's working OK, I'm just trying to get the "D4" part to not be hardcoded in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, but you have to use explicit `ToString` call like this:

```
string format = "D4";
string sequenceNumber = 
    $"{fieldValuePrefix.ToUpper()}{separator}{(similarPrefixes + 1).ToString(format)}";
```